# how to solve after pauseJob, resumeJob execute many times?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

```
JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(QuartzStudy.class).withIdentity("job1").build();
    CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .startAt(DateBuilder.evenSecondDate(new Date()))
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("*/5 * * * * ?").withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
            .build();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    scheduler.pauseJob(jobDetail.getKey());
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    scheduler.resumeJob(jobDetail.getKey());
```

after pauseJob, Thead sleep 10s,and then resumeJob, but execute many times

job1-DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1-14-Fri Jan 04 15:47:10 CST 2019

job1-DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2-15-Fri Jan 04 15:47:15 CST 2019

job1-DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3-16-Fri Jan 04 15:47:25 CST 2019

job1-DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4-17-Fri Jan 04 15:47:25 CST 2019

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @shriyog   i don`t want to resumeJob execute many times at once,wait time is right

Comment: Why are you pausing the job for 10 seconds if it's configured to run every 5th second? This question looks very contrived.